# Why is variable being incremented?

Tags: bash, variables, increment

Could someone help me figure why is the variable "$valorbase" in my script being incremented. It should continue the process for the next line when "$valorbase=8", though it happens only for the first line. Then it starts incrementing the numbers and dont stop when value 8 is reached.

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash


while read -r line <&3
do
valorbase=8
valor=0
echo "$line"
echo "Valor:"
read -r valor
echo "$valor" >&5
echo "||||||""$valor""|" >&6
valordasoma=$(awk -F"|" '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' < soma.txt)
var=$(awk -v  o1=$valordasoma  -v t1=$valorbase 'BEGIN { print (o1 >= t1)?"1":"0" }' < soma.txt)
if [[ $var -ge 1 ]]
then
  echo "Valor da soma > que, ou = ao valor base"
  echo "Repete comando para a linha"
else [[ $var -lt 1 ]]
    until [[ $var -eq 1 ]]
    do
    echo "Valor:"
    read -r valor
    echo "$valor" >&5
    echo "||||||""$valor""|" >&6
    valordasoma=$(awk -F"|" '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' < soma.txt)
    var=$(awk -v  o1=$valordasoma  -v t1=$valorbase 'BEGIN { print (o1 >= t1)?"1":"0" }' < soma.txt)
        if [[ $var -eq 1 ]]
        then
            > soma.txt
        else
            :
        fi
    done
fi
done 3<resultado.txt 5>soma.txt 6>partidasdobradas.txt
```

resultado.txt

```
TEST|    31|02/05/2015|6.1.1.01.001|2.1.1.01.005||8.100|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||31.000|N|N|||0.000|
TEST|    34|03/05/2015|6.1.1.01.002|2.1.1.01.005||6.900|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||34.000|N|N|||0.000|
TEST|    36|03/05/2015|6.1.1.01.002|2.1.1.01.005||8.900|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||36.000|N|N|||0.000|
TEST|    38|04/05/2015|6.1.1.01.001|2.1.1.01.005||13.490|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||38.000|N|N|||0.000|
TEST|    64|12/05/2015|6.1.1.01.001|2.1.1.01.005||6.780|DIVERSOS|||N|||   ||S|CB|||05|||||||64.000|N|N|||0.000|
```

Comment: I tried running your script, but I don't know what I'm supposed to enter in the Valor: prompt.

Comment: Sorry about that. Simply enter values/numbers (integers or decimals).

Comment: I knew that, but I didn't understand what the numbers mean.

Comment: Actually that is part of a script im making, which will reed reports from a financial management software, analise it and make some changes to finally output a report in a format accepted by an accounting software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to `soma.txt` using `>&5` inside the loop, it writes to the file at the current position in the file. When you truncate the file with `> soma.txt`, the current position isn't reset, so future writes go into the middle of the file, with a bunch of nulls at the beginning.

You should truncate the file before the loop, then use `5>>soma.txt` as the redirection of the loop, so it will write in *append* mode. This will make it automatically seek to the current end of the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

>soma.txt
while read -r line <&3
do
valorbase=8
valor=0
echo "$line"
echo "Valor:"
read -r valor
echo "$valor" >&5
echo "||||||""$valor""|" >&6
valordasoma=$(awk -F"|" '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' < soma.txt)
var=$(awk -v  o1=$valordasoma  -v t1=$valorbase 'BEGIN { print (o1 >= t1)?"1":"0" }' < soma.txt)
if [[ $var -ge 1 ]]
then
  echo "Valor da soma > que, ou = ao valor base"
  echo "Repete comando para a linha"
else [[ $var -lt 1 ]]
    until [[ $var -eq 1 ]]
    do
    echo "Valor:"
    read -r valor
    echo "$valor" >&5
    echo "||||||""$valor""|" >&6
    valordasoma=$(awk -F"|" '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' < soma.txt)
    var=$(awk -v  o1=$valordasoma  -v t1=$valorbase 'BEGIN { print (o1 >= t1)?"1":"0" }' < soma.txt)
        if [[ $var -eq 1 ]]
        then
            > soma.txt
        else
            :
        fi
    done
fi
done 3<resultado.txt 5>>soma.txt 6>partidasdobradas.txt
```

Comment: Barmar, appreciate your help. Its working perfectly!